# exclude category from WordPress Form function

Tags: categories, functions, forms

I have this function and I need to somehow exclude a category number 14 from my submission form. Is there any way to do it inside this function?

```
function retrieve_cat_data($byid = false){
    $massive_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0');

    if($byid):
        $massive_categories = array();  
        foreach ($massive_categories_obj as $massive_cat) {
            if($massive_cat->cat_ID != 1) $massive_categories[$massive_cat->cat_ID] = $massive_cat->cat_ID;
        }
        $categories_tmp = array_unshift($massive_categories, "0" ); 
    else:
        $massive_categories = array();  
        foreach ($massive_categories_obj as $massive_cat) {
            if($massive_cat->cat_ID != 1) $massive_categories[$massive_cat->cat_ID] = $massive_cat->cat_name;
        }
        $categories_tmp = array_unshift($massive_categories, __('Select a category:', 'bo') );      
    endif;

    return $massive_categories;
}


function retrieve_cat_data_sp( $exclude ){
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'exclude' => $exclude
    );
    $massive_categories_obj = get_categories($args);

    $massive_categories = array();  

    foreach ($massive_categories_obj as $massive_cat) { 
        if($massive_cat->cat_ID != 1) $massive_categories[$massive_cat->cat_ID] = $massive_cat->cat_ID;
    }
    $categories_tmp = array_unshift($massive_categories, "0" ); 

    return $massive_categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using the `exclude` array key in your [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) call?

e.g. change this:

```
$massive_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
```

to this:

```
$massive_categories_obj = get_categories('hide_empty=0&exclude=14');
```

Note that `exclude` expects a *comma-separated string* as a value.

For your second function, what are you passing as `$exclude`?

```
function retrieve_cat_data_sp( $exclude ){
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => '0',
        'exclude' => $exclude
    );
    $massive_categories_obj = get_categories($args);
```

Are you passing a *comma-separated string*, an *array*, or something else?

What do you get from this `get_categories( $args )` call? Try a `var_dump( $massive_categories_obj )` to see what it's returning?

Comment: it worked. It is a submit form, when chosen the category it displays the upload and submit button, if not, those are hidden.